# Cross-Implementation Deterministic Array#shuffle

Tags: ruby, jruby, rubinius

It is possible to pass a random number generator to `Array#shuffle` that makes the shuffle deterministic.

For example, in MRI 1.9.3p327:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle(random: Random.new(0)) # => [1, 2, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle(random: Random.new(0)) # => [1, 2, 4, 3]
```

However, the random number generator implementation of Random isn't specified. Because of this, other implementations of Ruby have different results.

In Rubinius 2.0.0rc1 (1.9.3 release 2012-11-02 JI):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle(random: Random.new(0)) # => [1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle(random: Random.new(0)) # => [1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Incidentally, jruby-1.7.1 uses the same random number generator as MRI 1.9.3p327, but this is just by chance, not guaranteed.

In order to have consistent-across-implementation deterministic shuffle, I would like to pass a custom random number generator into `Array#shuffle`. I thought this would be trivial to do, but it turns out to be quite complicated.

Here is what I tried first, in MRI:

```
class NotRandom; end
[1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle(random: NotRandom.new) # => [4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle(random: NotRandom.new) # => [4, 2, 1, 3]
```

I expected a `NoMethodError` telling me the interface I needed to implement.

Any insights?

---

UPDATE:

As @glebm points out, `NotRandom` inherited `Kernel#rand`, which is the interface needed. This is easily worked around, but unfortunately does not offer a solution.

```
class NotRandom
  def rand(*args)
    0
  end
end
```

In RBX:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle(random: NotRandom.new) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In MRI:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].shuffle(random: NotRandom.new) # => [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: What happens if you inherit `NotRandom` from `BasicObject` (as opposed to the default `Object`)?

Comment: @glebm That results in a NoMethodError!

Comment: Why do you want a deterministic shuffle and how is a deterministic shuffle different from a simple hard wired list of permutations?

Comment: @muistooshort I want to do a deterministic shuffle in a test context. I can accomplish this by injecting a random number generator. In production, I would use Random. In test, I would use NotRandom.

Comment: Your tests shouldn't fail just because `shuffle` is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the solution was a combination of two things:

1. Figure out the Random API. It's just `rand`.
2. Implement my own shuffle, because different Ruby implementations aren't consistent.

I used `my_array.sort_by { @random_generator.rand }`.