# How to Generate N random numbers from a SHA-256 Hash

Tags: ruby, bitcoin

I'm working on a "provably fair" site where let's say X participants enter into a drawing and we need to pick first 1 overall winner, but then ideally we also want to pick N sub-winners out of the X total.

(for the curious, the SHA-256 Hash will be the merkle tree root of a Bitcoin block at a pre-specified time)

So, given a SHA-256 hash, how do we generate N random numbers?

I think I know how to generate 1 random number (within ruby's Fixnum range). According to this article: http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/1/9/how-big-is-a-bignum

The maximum Fixnum integer is: 4611686018427387903

Let's pluck the first Y characters of the SHA-256 hash. We can generate one instead of relying on a Bitcoin merkle root with:

```
d = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest('hello')
> "2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824"
```

Let's take the first 6 characters, or: 2cf24d

Convert this to base 10:

```
'2cf24d'.to_i(16)
> 2945613
```

We now have a unique Fixnum based on our merkle root.

With X participants, let's say 17, we decide the winner with:

```
2945613 % 17
> 6
```

So assuming all entries know their order of entry, the sixth entrant can prove that they should be the winner.

Now -- what would be the best way to similarly pick N sub-winners? Let's say each of these entrants should get a smaller but still somewhat valuable prize.

Comment: This sounds like a dusty illegal gambling operation. The chain certainly has enough of those.

Comment: Crypto.SE: [Getting an integer from bytes](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/map-bytes-to-number), [Using a hash as PRNG](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9076/using-a-hash-as-a-secure-prng). Those are the pieces, now go have fun breaking the law. Try not to get hacked before you get arrested.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the hash for the seed?

```
[*1..17].shuffle(random: Random.new(0x2cf24d))
# => [15, 5, 9, 7, 14, 3, 16, 12, 2, 1, 17, 4, 6, 13, 11, 10, 8]
[*1..17].shuffle(random: Random.new(0x2cf24d))
# => [15, 5, 9, 7, 14, 3, 16, 12, 2, 1, 17, 4, 6, 13, 11, 10, 8]
```

EDIT: This is dependent on Ruby version though - I believe `shuffle` is different between JRuby and MRI, even though `Random` produces the same sequence. You could circumvent this by implementing `shuffle` yourself. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774225/cross-implementation-deterministic-arrayshuffle) for more details. This workaround works consistently for me in both JRuby and MRI:

```
r = Random.new(0x2cf24d)
[*1..17].sort_by { r.rand }
# => [14, 11, 4, 10, 1, 3, 9, 13, 16, 17, 12, 5, 8, 2, 6, 7, 15] 
r = Random.new(0x2cf24d)
[*1..17].sort_by { r.rand }
# => [14, 11, 4, 10, 1, 3, 9, 13, 16, 17, 12, 5, 8, 2, 6, 7, 15]
```